# Passing values from IntentService to Service

Tags: android

I would like to pass a variable from the IntentService to Service.

Assuming I have: MyService.java and MyIntentService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public static String myString = "";

}
```

---

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
MyService.myString = "My New String Value";
}

}
```

does it work like this? or should I use Intent.putextra(...) method?

Comment: Either way, there are multiple ways to solve most problems and they each have their strengths & weaknesses. Use whichever approach makes the most sense to you.

Comment: Both will work intent.putextra will not load your service class in memory if its not running calling static variable will load it in Myservice in memory